# Dismissing UITableViewController changes ADBannerView location

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, iad

I have set `ADBannerView` in last of `UITableViewController` it's working perfectly when have same view, but when I go to another view and dismiss it adview size changes.

here is code

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let tableBounds = tableView.bounds
    var bannerFrame = self.bannerView.frame

    bannerFrame = CGRect(x: tableBounds.origin.x, y: tableBounds.origin.y + CGRectGetHeight(tableBounds) - CGRectGetHeight(bannerFrame), width: tableBounds.size.width, height: bannerFrame.size.height)
    bannerView.frame = bannerFrame
}
```

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
let tableBounds = tableView.bounds
```

with

```
let tableBounds = tableView.frame
```